# In Java, is there a way to set a line in a method to return to at any point later in the method?

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm learning to program in Java and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to set a return point in a method in case a user decides they want to go back. For example, within a method, I ask the user to choose between one of three options:

1) Register

2) Search

3) Other

Let's say that the user chooses to register. This choice then presents them with two new options:

1) Register as User

2) Register as Admin

Let's say that they choose to register as an admin. They are then prompted to enter their information, but maybe halfway through they realize "Wait! I want to register as a user, not an admin!". Typing in "back" is also an option, and if they do so, I want to be able to take them back to the menu where they choose between user and admin, not all the way back to the beginning. Is there a way to do this? I know I could use loops, but my program is a bit more complicated than my example, so I would rather not if I can get around it. I'm looking for a way similar to the way you can name loops in assembly language, so that you can just say "go to this point" and it goes back without the user having to re-enter all the information that they did before the sub menu that they want to get to. (I realize that in my example they don't enter any info until that sub menu. In my actual program they do.)

Any ideas? If worse comes to worse, I'm not opposed to using a loop. Just figured I would ask!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using loops is as good a method as any. Two suggestions:

- you might want to read up on the [`break`-with-label statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html); and/or
- you might want to place each menu into a separate function to make the structure clear.

Comment: +1 for the link to java dirty little secret... Yes, Virginia, there *is* a `goto`!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have methods for each of these options. At any point if user wants to go to some option, just return from the existing method with some value which indicates the option user wants to jump to. From the main code, just go to the appropriate method depending on the option selected.

Also, each method may take input of the parent (id), so going back won't be a problem.

This way you can go back to the parent or to some other option from any point in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at it the wrong way.  You don't need to go back to a point in your code to do an undo or rewind, you need to create the logic to be able to change a decision and make it work with whatever data has been entered so far.

So for example, you would use a data structure to hold all the data that a user enters, and if he chooses to change his registration type, you'll be able to fill in his info from that data structure.  He can also decide that the address he gave you is wrong and change it, you'll still want to keep all the data you got so far, regardless if he's changing from user to admin.

The point is, you are looking at this in a sequential way, as if code can only run forward and backward in a straight line, while Java and even assembly are not at all sequential, you can go in every direction, skip to some logical point in time, and jump back to where you were.